# Proof or Translation of Deuring's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Lenstra's paper on elliptic curve factorization references a result of Deuring, which states (the precise statement is copied from [this paper](http://www.math.mtu.edu/~ethans/pdf/hurwitz_class_sums.pdf)):

> If $r$ is an integer such that $\vert r\vert<2\sqrt{p}$, then the number of isomorphism classes over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with exactly $p+1-r$ points is equal to the number of equivalence classes of binary quadratic forms with discriminant $r^2-4p$.

Is there an English translation of Duering's original paper anywhere, or does anyone know of a proof in English?

Comment: This is Theorem $7$, and an english reference is given: H. W. Lenstra, Jr. Factoring integers with elliptic curves. Ann. of Math. (2), 126(3):649–673, 1987.

Comment: Yes, Lenstra's paper is what I was looking at originally. He also simply states the result without proof.

Comment: This is Theorem 14.18 in Cox, Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$.